# JavaScript select all siblings past an element

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to select all siblings past a certain element, like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>Unselected</li>
    <li>Unselected</li>
    <li id="start">Start Here</li>
    <li>Selected</li>
    <li>Selected</li>
    <li>Selected</li>
</ul>
```

I cannot plan for the amount of siblings to select or the number at which it will start, so I'm guessing that there will need to be a `.length` in there at some point.

Vanilla JS only please :) Thanks!

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy I assume, after the #start

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can select those elements by using `~` selector,

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll("#start ~ li");
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/oa0Ljxjb/)

Comment: I didn't realize the `~` selector starts after the first selector. That's a great solution, thanks!

Comment: @jasonetco Glad to help! :)

Answer (score 2):

To iterate over the siblings, just use `nextElementSibling`:

```
var e = document.getElementById("start");
while (e = e.nextElementSibling) e.classList.add("selected");
```

```js
var e = document.getElementById("start");
while (e = e.nextElementSibling) e.classList.add("selected");
```

```css
.selected {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Unselected</li>
    <li>Unselected</li>
    <li id="start">Start Here</li>
    <li>Selected</li>
    <li>Selected</li>
    <li>Selected</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

`var node = document.getElementById("start")`
`var sibling = node.nextElementSibling;`

This will return the sibling immediately after the node, or null no more siblings are available.

Comment: OP asks about **all siblings**, not the single one.

Comment: Yes I understood. Thanks, anyways I'll not be able to delete my answer now, I can do it in next 12 hours